# How to Edit Eclipse' Naming Convention

Tags: eclipse, naming-conventions, pascalcasing

Question is simple: how to edit naming convention of Eclipse?

I have two specific issues:

1. I want to use Pascal Naming Convention instead of camel for fields,
   such as MyField instead of myField.
2. I want eclipse to generate the getter and setter codes as
   Get{Field_Name} or Set{Field_Name}. So it will generate GetMyField
   instead of getMyField.

I searched the whole web, but could not find any solution.

Please don't suggest me to use the Java Naming Conventions. It is a must for me to use that naming conventions on the project I am running. I am not good at Preferences of Eclipse. I checked it out but couldn't find a place to edit these.

If there isn't any option to change that, I guess, changing a template in one of the resource file eclipse should work.

Does anyone know how to edit that naming conventions or templates?

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but under `Windows->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Templates` you can add a template like this:

```
const ${type} Get${name}() const {return m_${name};}
```

This will generate

```
const type Getname() const {return m_name;}
```

and highlight type, you type the return type and hit Tab, that will highlight `name` you type the name of the field and it changes in both places. If you don't use m_ just remove that from the template.